# GeoJSON source to other vector source OL 3

Tags: openlayers

I have a vector layer with markers. I have another vector layer with a route from geoJSON, but the route should be together with the marker to switch the layer and to fill a sidebar.

Is there any idea for me as a newbie?

My code:

```
var RSource = new ol.source.Vector({features: RFeature});
var RLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({source: RSource});

/*var R170 = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
      url: '/gpx/bonar.geojson',
      format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
}),
style: function(feature) {
      return style[feature.getGeometry().getType()];
}
});
*/
R170S =  new ol.source.Vector({
      url: '/gpx/bonar.geojson',
      format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
});

var RLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
source: [R170S, RSource]
});
}
```

....

Also I have no idea with the styling.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would say that merging points (markers) and lines in the same layer is a weird idea and may be impossible (?). How could you define a style for this point-and-line layer if merged?

Grouping layers is probably what you are looking for:

```
var layersGroup = new ol.layer.Group({
    layers: [
        layer1,
        layer2
    ]
})
```

So define your two layers and their styles separately and then group them.

Comment: later I need the source and

Comment: later I need the source and extent of the features to fill a sidebar. It was not possible for me to get the feature function and the source of the geoJSON layer. Different styles should be possible by style function. (for instance in the geoJSON file)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, for that just load your geojson file by yourself then add the features received to your existing source:

```
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.open('GET', '/gpx/bonar.geojson');
client.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var features = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(client.responseText);
  RSource.addFeatures(features);
});
```

Then to specify a different style for point and line :

```
  var styles = {
    'Point': new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: 5,
        fill: null,
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: 'red', width: 1})
      });
  }),
    'LineString': new ol.style.Style({
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: 'green',
        width: 1
      })
    })
  };

  var RLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: RSource ,
    style:  function(feature) {
      return styles[feature.getGeometry().getType()];
    }
  });
```

Code untested. [See this official example](http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/geojson.html?q=Style)